# Show simle view from ios module in titanium appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium

I am new to titanium development and i am developing an iOS module. I just want to know the flow of how i can show the view from ios (xcode development) to the titanium. I read the titanium document for it but it is very unclear and i did not get the good idea. I read there is something TIproxyview and UIview which can be used to show view in titanium but i didn't understand that document. So anyone can please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch this presentation: http://vimeo.com/103633347, and these are the slides: http://www.slideshare.net/omorandi/ticonfeu2014 . I has all you need to get started.

Also there's a bunch of Open Source Titanium Modules here: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules .  Reading the code could help.

I agree that the documentation is not great on the Modules side, but at least there's many community developers who can help you out.

HTH,

R